# Windows Phone: Changing a TextBlock style at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am making a sort of checklist app. There are a series of TextBlocks in a StackPanel which when clicked on call:

```
public void TextBlock1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        (App.Current as App).detailTitle = "Check 1";
        (App.Current as App).detailMessage = "This is item 1";
        (App.Current as App).pageReferrer = "pivot1.Check1";
        Uri detailPage = new Uri("/DetailPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        NavigationService.Navigate(detailPage);
    }
```

Then on the detailPage.xaml:

```
public DetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DetailPageTitle.Text = (App.Current as App).detailTitle;
        textBlockDetail.Text = (App.Current as App).detailMessage;
    }

    private void doneButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.GoBack();
    }
```

Now when the doneButton_Click happens I want the referring TextBlock style to be changed from PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle to one I created called TextBlockStyleClicked.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static class FrameworkElementExtensions
{
    public static object TryFindResource(this FrameworkElement element, object resourceKey)
    {
        var currentElement = element;

        while (currentElement != null)
        {
            var resource = currentElement.Resources[resourceKey];
            if (resource != null)
            {
                return resource;
            }

            currentElement = currentElement.Parent as FrameworkElement;
        }

        return Application.Current.Resources[resourceKey];
    }
}
```

using:

```
ApplicationTitle.Style = (Style) ApplicationTitle.TryFindResource("PhoneTextTitle1Style");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would I implement this, I'm new to WP8 development.

Comment: What causes the problem? Here is a simple example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31216763/PhoneApp1.rar